# How do I pass fields to 'new()' using the crate 'derive_new' v0.5.9 but not storing them in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'd like to do this using the crate 'derive_new':

```rust
#[derive(new)]
struct Test
{
    #[new(value = "std::rc::Rc::new(_val.clone())")]
    data: std::rc::Rc<String>,

    _val: String
}
```

But I don't want to store '_val' (and avoid the clone). Is there a way to do this with 'derive_new'?

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: Can you please post how you'd like to _use_ the struct?  What would your line initializing the struct look like, versus how it's declared?  And/or, if `#[derive(new)]` didn't exist, what would your struct _alone_ look like, and how (ideally) do you want to initialize it?  This appears to be a partial fragment of your implementation of using the crate.  I find I would like some clarification on what you're trying to do.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to create a self-referential struct?

Comment: The point of the `derive_new` crate is reducing boiler plate code that's always the same. If the desired code is different than the standard case, just write it yourself – that's way more readable anyway, since people will understand your code at a glance, instead of first having to figure out what the `derive_new` crate is and how it works.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Well I think adding 'new(init)' would be nice, like Python's dataclass InitVar. It'd still accomplish the goal of reducing boilerplate code, with with the added benefit of allowing parametric initialization of fields.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#init-only-variables

Comment: I personally wouldn't use the crate at all, since it saves hardly any code at the cost of making the code way more obscure, so I'm probably not the best person to judge whether this feature would be useful. From a quick glance at the docs it appears that it at least doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I use it for almost all my classes, it saves a lot of code. Well, you can't avoid "obscurity" using derive. All derive-new does is create your 'new' function conveniently.

Comment: @KevinAnderson It's just for parametric initialization of fields. Nothing fancy. 'derive_new' forces you to store the parameter. I just need that parameter for the init.

Comment: I use [rust-analyzer's "Generate `new`" action](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#generate_new), which generates a standard constructor with a key press, which I can then customize as needed. Lower compile times, much easier to read for people who don't know `derive_new`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Well knowing derive-new is very easy. The problem with generate-new action is that the code looks better if just just use 'derive_new'. Like using '#[derive(Debug]' instead of an automatic debug implement creator action. The only customization I need is something like Python's dataclasss InitVar, like '#[new(init)]'. I expected to be able to do this using some other mechanism (like derivative or similar).

Comment: Fair enough, I'm not trying to convince you to do something else.